# curl: add string as option in bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl, post, string

I'd like to pass a variable string to command options in curl.

```
if [ ! -z ${picture} ]; then APISTRING+="--data-urlencode \"picture=${picture}\" ";fi
if [ ! -z ${additional} ]; then APISTRING+="--data-urlencode \"additional_info="${additional}"\" ";fi
```

So if picture and additional aren't empty, the $APISTRING should be:

```
--data-urlencode "picture=someinfo"  --data-urlencode "additional_info=additional infos here"
```

But when I'm calling curl

```
curl -v -X "POST" --url "https://example.org/api" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" "${APISTRING}"
```

It give an error like

> curl: option --data-urlencode "picture=someinfo"  --data-urlencode
>   "additional_info=additional infos here": is unknown

Does anyone has an idea how to handle this?

Comment: See [**But what if …?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408#286350)

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 3):

Embedding quotes in a variable's value, like `APISTRING+="--data-urlencode \"picture=${picture}\" "` does not work right. When you try to use `$APISTRING`, bash parses quotes before expanding the variable's value, and it doesn't rescan for "new" quotes after expansion. As a result, the quotes are treated as part of the string, rather than as delimiters around the string.

The best solution for things like this is to use an array to store the command options:

```
APISTRING=()
if [ ! -z ${picture} ]; then APISTRING+=(--data-urlencode "picture=${picture}");fi
if [ ! -z ${additional} ]; then APISTRING+=(--data-urlencode "additional_info=${additional}");fi
curl -v -X "POST" --url "https://example.org/api" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" "${APISTRING[@]}"
```

Note that arrays are not available in all POSIX shells, so you should only use this in scripts you explicitly use bash for (i.e. a shebang of either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, *not* `#!/bin/sh`). Also, the syntax is very picky; don't leave off any of the parentheses in the assignments, the double-quotes, or the `[@]` when expanding the array.

BTW, there is another possible solution. Rather than accumulating the optional options beforehand, you can use [conditional expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_an_alternate_value) to include them on the spot:

```
curl -v -X "POST" --url "https://example.org/api" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" \
    ${picture:+ --data-urlencode "picture=${picture}"} \
    ${additional:+ --data-urlencode "additional_info=${additional}"}
```

Here, the `:+` expansion tells bash to check whether the variable's nonblank, and if it is to not use it, but an alternate value: the quoted version of the variable with the appropriate prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary quotes in "${APISTRING}":

fix:

```
curl -v -X "POST" --url "https://example.org/api" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" ${APISTRING}
```